# Foreach loop iteration issue while sending email and sms inside it

Tags: php, mysql, curl, foreach

I am running a PHP function regularly with support of WGET linux command (like CRON). In this case, for every execution, I will take 1500 records from my database, and iterate through foreach loop. Inside the foreach, I need to run a for loop with limit of 20 iterations. Inside the for loop, I will check the current action using switch case.

```
$samplearray = array('.....'); // Multidimensional array contains 1500 rows
foreach($samplearray as $samplearr)
{
     for($s=1;$s<=20;$s++)
     {
          $step = mysql_query("SELECT steptype FROM steptable WHERE camapign=$samplearr['campaign'] AND currentstep=$s")or die(mysql_error());
          $stepdet = mysql_fetch_array($step);
          switch($stepdet ['steptype'])
          {
               case 'email':
                   // PHP mailer script to send emails
               break;
               case 'sms':
                   // Third party URL to send SMS using Curl execution
               break;
               case 'others':
                   // DB updations - Mysql Query
               break;
               // DB updations - Mysql Query
          }
     }
}
```

Here, the problem is, if the case contains 'email' or 'sms', duplicates are sending.

For e.g. in 1500 iterations, more than 2500 emails are sent. I don't know where the problem occurs.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Because of the for loop, every entry in the `$samplearray` that matches `email` or `sms` will be sent 20 times.

Comment: Why do you not understand the code that you wrote? You have an outer loop of 1,500 iterations and an inner loop of 20, so your switch statement will be run 30,000 times.

Comment: and to help understand how your code is working  reduce the array to 10 elements and the counter to 2, and add debug print statements showing the values for current array element and the counter. Good luck.

Comment: I don't quite see how you could `not` see how this is sending duplicates. It looks like you have intentionally written the code to send 20 times per array value.

Comment: Thaillie, sorry i have missed few lines in the code. I have added it now. The duplicate count has no pattern to find the issue. For eq,. In a scenarion of 1500 iterations, 700 emails sent by single time, 300 email sent twice, 500 emails thrice. These count varies for consecutive iterations. If i hide the emails and SMS part inside the case, its working properly (have checked in DB).

Comment: It seems DB contains 2500 records for email matches, so it is sending 2500 emails

Comment: Lock, why i am using for loop here is, i need to find the current action from 'steptable' table. It may contain various values like email, SMS, date timer, others, etc. In which, i need to fetch the current value of the current iteration. Based on that value, I am doing actions in switch cases.